# Executing a prepared statement within a query

Tags: mysql, prepared-statement

I have this below piece of code. I would like to populate the KPI_RESULTS table using computed data from variable data. The variable data receives different fomulas. eg( n1*n7)*100 depending on the definition of the KPI fomula by the engineer. n1 ----n! are column names.

Am however getting an error when I try to execute the below scripts.

```
enter code here

set @data = 'n2/n1';
set @s = Concat("select datetime , element NODE,",@data," RESULTS from loas");
PREPARE STMT FROM @s;

INSERT INTO KPI_results(date_time,node_name,results) values(execute STMT );
```

Comment: What is the error that you're getting back?

Comment: `set @data = 'n2/n1'` here `'n2/n1'` is being treat as a string thats your issue.

Comment: Am getting the below error. MySQL Database Error: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'STMT )' at line 1"

Comment: @milkshake when I execute the command execute STMT outside the insert command all is fine. The issue is about executing the command execute STMT where am getting the error.

Comment: why dont you try swapping `'n2/n1'` for `"n2/n1"`

Comment: No change even after the swapping

Comment: @milkshake, not germane.  LoneHacker wants to use the *string* `'n2/n1'` to dynamically generate his SQL query string.  `n2` and `n1` will later be correctly parsed as column names, if the OP can surmount his syntax error.

Answer (score 0):

That's unfortunately not supported.  You'll have to PREPARE the dynamically generated INSERT query you want to run instead:

```
mysql> set @formula='n2/n1'
mysql> set @sql = CONCAT('INSERT INTO KPI_results SELECT foo, bar, ', @formula, ' FROM t')
mysql> PREPARE stmt FROM @sql
mysql> EXECUTE stmt
```

Comment: Thanks a lot pilcrow. Its most unfortunate. I however had to handle this from using PHP code. 
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($res, MYSQL_NUM)) {
    $k_name=$row[1];
    $fomula=$row[2];
    

$str ="INSERT INTO kpi_results(Date_time,node_name,results)(select datetime , element NODE," . $fomula ." from loas)";
    $results=@mysql_query($str);
    if (!$results){
    $message  = 'ERROR : ' . mysql_error() . "\n";
    $message .= 'QUERRY: ' . $query;
    die($message);
}
}